# Suitescript - For nlapiSendEmail(), can I have the sender be an email NOT on an employee record?

Tags: email, netsuite, suitescript, sender

I would like to send an email through suitescript that has a sender of a generic email account from the company (accounting@xxx.com) without having to setup an Accounting User email or having that be an email on someone's employee record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The employee record doesn't require "access"(thus no user seat is consumed) so I'm not sure why it would matter having it setup.

If you **REALLY** wanted to avoid having that *extra* employee record around, you could create it, send the email, then delete it again... anytime you needed to send an email.

Comment: Some customers have  half dozen or so dummy employees just for working with nlapiSendEmail. It's quite harmless.

Comment: Same here.  We sometimes even encourage them to break them up functionally, especially if they're interested in referencing/reviewing the emails inside NS.